# visjs timeline change CSS on top

Tags: css, vis.js, vis.js-timeline

I'm trying to change the css of the top (the part showing the dates) of a vis.js timeline. My code so far is this

```
.vis-time-axis.vis-foreground .vis-major, .vis-time-axis.vis-foreground .vis-minor, .vis-panel.vis-top {
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
}
```

this gives me a result like this:

[image]

compared with the timeline without my changes, I have now lost the seperating vertical line between days and also between the time
[image]

Do anybody knows how to fix the css?

I also have a problem to set the background-color on the "field" over the groups, so any help on this will also be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
.vis-time-axis .vis-grid.vis-minor, .vis-time-axis .vis-grid.vis-major {
  border-color:red;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Javier/x52toyr9/6/

Comment: Thanks but it only colors the borders, which are visible, it does not change that my back-ground color overwrites them (hides them)